# Mediainfo recognising jpg files as video. Glitch or jpg fie issue?

Tags: windows-10, jpeg, media-info, tooltip

So i've just scanned a bunch of photos and the resulting files are just standard JPG but for some reason MediaInfo is picking them up as Video?

For instance i have a 1.86mb jpg file (according to windows properties) but mediainfo hover over tooltip says:

```
MediaInfo:
JPEG: 101 MiB
Video: 3524*2353 (3:2), JPEG
```

And the info from within mediaInfo itself says:

```
General
Complete name                            : img009.jpg
Format                                   : JPEG
File size                                : 101 MiB

Video
Format                                   : JPEG
Width                                    : 3 524 pixels
Height                                   : 2 353 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 3:2
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 101 MiB (100%)
```

Any idea why, or how to fix? It doesnt do this on other non scanned jpg files, it just identifies them correcty as images with the correct filesize.

Ps. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask so i'm sorry if it is.

Comment: If you get no answer here try...https://sourceforge.net/p/mediainfo/discussion/297610/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance i have a [...]

For instance you have several files, with file names having sequential numbers.

This is considered by MediaInfo as a sequence of images, so a video stream, as it is used this way by several (professional) MediaInfo users. Can not currently be deactivated in the graphical interface.

Comment: Thank you for that info, i never knew that about sequential images.